# Adding values from button to UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am learning Xcode(objective C). I want to make simple calculator.

I started by adding four simple buttons and one label. Two buttons are for numbers(1 and 2), and I added variables into .m file:

```
int *one = 1;
int *two = 2;
```

Next step what I've done is that I made action on button clicked and said that label take value from that button:

```
self.firstLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", one);
```

And I made same action for another button.

Everything is fine until this step, what I want to do next is when I click on number button to add value to that label, then when I click to divide(/) button to add / sign and when I click to another button to add another value.

I want to be something like this in label: 2 / 1, and when i click = button to divide them and show result. Thanks.

**EDIT**:

I also added label proper into .h, and when I click on button it shows me only one value in label.

Comment: You don't want `int *one = 1;`. You want `int one = 1;`. `int` is a primitive type so you don't want a pointer.

Comment: Ok, I changed that but it didn't solve the problem...

Comment: Please share you button actions also. I did not understand it.  Try to share more code, there can be simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are just starting to learn obj C you may want to keep your calculator simple, building a fully functional calc. can get surprisingly complex.  You should consider using an [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) approach, it will make things much easier, you can just push the numbers to a stack and perform operations one at a time. 
Something like: 2, enter, 1, enter + enter.

You may also want to have a look at [Stanford's iOS course on Apple University](https://itunes.apple.com/bj/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099), the course is in Swift but the class project was a calculator so it should give you a good reference point.  Hope that helps and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you should add a custom target for each button, i.e.,

```
- (IBAction)addDivide:(id)sender {
    self.firstLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ /", self.firstLabel.text];
}
```

Any action will update your label.

Just a further advice for you, don't name the label as "firstLabel", try to give it a name tied to its semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting the int value to the label. You need to append the value maintaining the previous text so that it appears as "2 / 1".
I'll suggest using tags for the buttons and use a common method for number buttons in your calculator.
This is more sort of logical thing rather than specific to iOS and Xcode.
Similarly when "=" is pressed use a method to calculate the result.